# Group By HEIDISQL

Tags: mysql, heidisql

Estoy queriendo hacer una consulta a `Heidi SQL` pero me tira error cuando utilizo un Group By, Cómo puedo hacer para que los datos no se repitan si no puedo utilizarlo?

Me tira el siguiente problema:

> Error de SQL (1055): Expression #2 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'bdTest.p.Pedido' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by

Esta es mi consulta:

```
select DISTINCT e.Entrega, p.Pedido, p.Remito, e.Fecha 
from Entrega e inner JOIN Pedido p ON e.Entrega = p.Entrega
 WHERE e.Fecha BETWEEN '2022-09-20 00-00-00' AND '2022-09-23 24-00-00' 
 GROUP BY e.Entrega;
```

Si la consulta la hago en `phpMyAdmin` funciona perfecto.

Comment: Agrega lo que te pide: `GROUP BY e.Entrega, p.Pedido, p.Remito, e.Fecha`

Comment: Pero si agrego eso se me repiten los datos

Comment: no es que se repitan, tienes columnas con valores iguales, pero una de ellas es distinta, de lo contrario se agruparía todo.

Comment: Ahi lei la respuesa que dieron, aora entendí porque se usan todos los campos, muchas gracias!